# Why an obvious condition is not fulfilled?

Tags: ruby

I work on task about schedule and have class and .yml file where i want to retrieve data as "start" point, "end" point, "price" etc. And in my class I have method, where i want to determine if stations equal to user choice:

```
class Train 
  require 'yaml'

  def initialize(time)
    @time = YAML.load_file(time)
  end

  def calc(begin:, end:)
    ary = @time['time']
    start = begin
    stop = end
    res = []
    loop do
      tmp = ary.find { |h| h['begin'] == start }
      break unless tmp
      res << tmp
      start = tmp['end']
      break if start == stop
    end
  end
end
```

But it always fails on condition

```
break unless tmp
```

For example if write instance variable

```
a = Train.new("my_path_to yml") 
a.calc(begin: ':washington', end: ':tokyo')
```

It executes nothing. Even if I refactor loop block and write "for" iterator it throw "else" condition:

```
for i in ary
  if i['begin'] == 'washington'
    puts "good"
  else
    puts "no way"
  end
end
```

Here is my .yml file

```
time:
  -
    begin: :washington
    end: :briston
    time: 6
    price: 3
  -
    begin: :briston
    end: :dallas
    time: 4
    price: 2
  -
    begin: :dallas
    end: :tokyo
    time: 3.5
    price: 3
  -
    begin: :tokyo
    end: :chicago
    time: 3.5
    price: 3
  -
    begin: :chicago
    end: :dellawer
    time: 3.5
    price: 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up strings (`'foo'`) and symbols (`:foo`), so your comparison doesn't match.

Comment: Old Chinese proverb: "Grief comes to those who use keywords as names of variables or methods."

Comment: One other thing to note: Move your `require` to the very top of the file. You should be up-front about your dependencies whenever possible, not hide them in the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this change, check comments in code:

```
def calc(begin_:, end_:) # <-- don't call variables begin or end, they are reserved words
  ary = @time['time']
  start = begin_
  stop = end_
  res = []
  loop do
    tmp = ary.find { |h| h['begin'] == start }
    break unless tmp
    res << tmp
    start = tmp['end']
    break if start == stop
  end
  res # <-- return something
end
```

Call as:

```
train.calc(begin_: :washington, end_: :tokyo)
#=> [{"begin"=>:washington, "end"=>:briston, "time"=>6, "price"=>3}, {"begin"=>:briston, "end"=>:dallas, "time"=>4, "price"=>2}, {"begin"=>:dallas, "end"=>:tokyo, "time"=>3.5, "price"=>3}]
```

---

**Take care not messing up strings with symbols.**

```
  ary.each do |i| # for i in ary <-- pythonic! :)
    if i['begin'] == :washington # <-- should be a symbol to pass, not a string
      puts "good"
    else
      puts "no way"
    end
  end
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile to explain the problem with the OP's code. I think I understand the problem but don't see why it would give rise to the error the OP mentioned. Suppose we have `def a(begin:); b = begin; c = 99; end; puts "b=#{b}, c=#{c}"; end`. Then `a(begin:1)` displays `b=99, c=99`. In `b = begin`, `begin` is the keyword, not the key. In the OP's code `end` appears to not be treated as a keyword in `stop = end`. Perhaps the line must begin with `end` for `end` to be treated as a keyword. If so, the `begin` block has started and will continue until the next keyword `end` is reached.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm getting `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end --- stop = end` while he says the error is around `break unless tmp`.

Comment: I got the same error in the simplified example in my comment above with the change `def a(begin:, end:)` and `c = end` rather than `c = 99`.